# How to make a frequency table out of dates but have every week as a part of the table?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

So I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
library(lubridate)

data <- data.frame(date = c("7/29/2021 21:18", "7/6/2021 20:37", "7/23/2021 20:11", "7/23/2021 21:35", 
                "7/23/2021 21:42", "7/23/2021 21:47", "10/11/2021 14:45", "10/11/2021 15:57", 
                "10/11/2021 16:23", "7/29/2021 15:52", "9/7/2021 14:36", "8/31/2021 21:05", 
                "8/25/2021 18:22", "6/28/2021 14:52", "10/8/2021 19:34", "7/19/2021 15:38", 
                "10/27/2021 21:09", "10/8/2021 15:56", "9/21/2021 17:20", "8/25/2021 20:42", 
                "8/30/2021 20:28", "5/20/2021 14:58", "11/1/2021 21:09", "11/1/2021 20:15", 
                "8/5/2021 16:17", "6/30/2021 20:12", "5/14/2021 17:36", "5/19/2021 20:40", 
                "5/20/2021 21:06", "5/19/2021 20:59"))

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(Num = week(as.Date(data$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))) %>% 
  arrange(Num) %>% 
  group_by(Num) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n())


print(data)

# A tibble: 13 x 2
     Num Count
   <dbl> <int>
 1    20     5
 2    26     2
 3    27     1
 4    29     1
 5    30     6
 6    31     1
 7    34     2
 8    35     2
 9    36     1
10    38     1
11    41     5
12    43     1
13    44     2
```

My problem with this is that the weeks are in number format and there are some weeks missing for example 42. I would like to see missing weeks even if there is no count. Is there a better way to do this?

My desired output would be something like where I can see the first monday of the week

```
Num  Date       Count
1   1/4/2021     0
2   1/11/2021    1
3   1/18/2021    3
```

Best,

Comment: Why is the Count for expected 1 and 3 when those are missing in the data

Answer (score 3):

To get the first day of every week, you can use `floor_date()` from lubridate. The `week_start` argument lets you start your weeks on Mondays, because it starts them on Sundays otherwise.

To fill in the 0s where you don't have any data, you can use tidyr's `complete()`.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tibble(date_chr = c(
  "7/29/2021 21:18",
  "7/6/2021 20:37",
  "7/23/2021 20:11",
  "7/23/2021 21:35",
  "7/23/2021 21:42",
  "7/23/2021 21:47",
  "10/11/2021 14:45",
  "10/11/2021 15:57",
  "10/11/2021 16:23",
  "7/29/2021 15:52",
  "9/7/2021 14:36",
  "8/31/2021 21:05",
  "8/25/2021 18:22",
  "6/28/2021 14:52"))


first_weekdays <- data %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(mdy_hm(date_chr)),
         first_weekday = floor_date(date, "week", week_start = 1)) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  print()
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#>    date_chr         date       first_weekday
#>    <chr>            <date>     <date>       
#>  1 6/28/2021 14:52  2021-06-28 2021-06-28   
#>  2 7/6/2021 20:37   2021-07-06 2021-07-05   
#>  3 7/23/2021 20:11  2021-07-23 2021-07-19   
#>  4 7/23/2021 21:35  2021-07-23 2021-07-19   
#>  5 7/23/2021 21:42  2021-07-23 2021-07-19   
#>  6 7/23/2021 21:47  2021-07-23 2021-07-19   
#>  7 7/29/2021 21:18  2021-07-29 2021-07-26   
#>  8 7/29/2021 15:52  2021-07-29 2021-07-26   
#>  9 8/25/2021 18:22  2021-08-25 2021-08-23   
#> 10 8/31/2021 21:05  2021-08-31 2021-08-30   
#> 11 9/7/2021 14:36   2021-09-07 2021-09-06   
#> 12 10/11/2021 14:45 2021-10-11 2021-10-11   
#> 13 10/11/2021 15:57 2021-10-11 2021-10-11   
#> 14 10/11/2021 16:23 2021-10-11 2021-10-11

count_by_week <- first_weekdays %>% 
  count(first_weekday) %>% 
  complete(first_weekday = seq.Date(min(first_weekday),
                                    max(first_weekday),
                                    "7 days"),
           fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  print()
#> # A tibble: 16 x 2
#>    first_weekday     n
#>    <date>        <dbl>
#>  1 2021-06-28        1
#>  2 2021-07-05        1
#>  3 2021-07-12        0
#>  4 2021-07-19        4
#>  5 2021-07-26        2
#>  6 2021-08-02        0
#>  7 2021-08-09        0
#>  8 2021-08-16        0
#>  9 2021-08-23        1
#> 10 2021-08-30        1
#> 11 2021-09-06        1
#> 12 2021-09-13        0
#> 13 2021-09-20        0
#> 14 2021-09-27        0
#> 15 2021-10-04        0
#> 16 2021-10-11        3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>